# What is meant by self-policing?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I search and I found the meaning of Self-policing that:

"The act or action of supervising the activities or policies of one's own group in order to prevent or detect and address violations of rules and regulations without outside enforcement."

Here one word is about the whole group but the single word **SELF** means only one person or we can say it is about one person. Why self-policing is used for the whole group not for the one person?

Comment: The "group" is a singular entity, so self-policing can apply to a group.

Answer (score 1):

"Self" does not always refer to one person. I might say that "the group polices itself"  In this case the reflexive pronoun contains "self" but it clearly doesn't refer to a person.

Similarly, in compounds like "self-policing", the word "self" can refer to a group. You could, perhaps, talk about a self-policing person (someone who controls their behaviour without external authority) It is more likely to refer to an organisation, that has internal mechanisms to regulate and control wrongdoing within the organisation.

> The drinks industry setup a self-policing organisation to regulate advertising and promote responsible drinking.

Answer (score 0):

That is the original meaning of "self", Maryam, but like many words, "self" has extended its meaning, particularly in compounds.

Compounds starting "self-" are often used of entities and institutions comprising many people. A prominent examples is *self-governing* (a calque of the Greek-derived *autonomous*), used of polities such as colonies and partial states.